# comparison between $H^i(Y,Rf_*\mathcal{F})$ and $H^i(Y,f_* \mathcal{F})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of ringed space, let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$ module, since $f_*$ is left exact we can derive it, and if $\mathcal{F}$ has injective resolution $\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{I}^\cdot$ then $Rf_* \mathcal{F}$ is represented by $f_*\mathcal{I}^\cdot$

Therefore we have $H^1(Y,Rf_*\mathcal{F}) = H^1(\Gamma(Y,f_*\mathcal{I}^\cdot))$

On the other hand we have $H^1(Y, f_*\mathcal{F})$, however $f_*\mathcal{I}^\cdot$ no longer be the resolution of $f_*\mathcal{F}$ (since $f_*$ is not exact ). Is it possible to compare $H^1(Y,f_*\mathcal{F})$ and $H^1(\Gamma(Y,f_*\mathcal{I}^\cdot))$ then? For example is $H^1(Y,f_*\mathcal{F}) \subset H^1(\Gamma(Y,f_*\mathcal{I}^\cdot))$?

Comment: Key words: Leray spectral sequence.

Comment: Thank you Hank Scorpio,  I will try to figure it out later.(before next week)

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but you might want to observe $H^k(Y, Rf_* \mathcal F) = H^k(X, \mathcal F)$, since $\Gamma(Y, f_* \mathcal I^k) = \Gamma(X, \mathcal I^k)$. In particular if $f$ is affine and $X,Y$ are noetherian seperated schemes, then $H^k(Y, f_* \mathcal F) = H^k(X, \mathcal F)$, using Chech cohomology.

Comment: Thank you for your comment red_trumpet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Leray spectral sequence, we have the following [five term exact sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-term_exact_sequence):

$$0\to H^1(Y,f_*\mathcal{F}) \to H^1(X,\mathcal{F}) \to H^0(Y,R^1f_*\mathcal{F}) \to ...$$

Therefore $H^1(Y,f_*\mathcal{F}) \subset H^1(X,\mathcal{F}) = H^1(Y,Rf_*\mathcal{F})$.